# How do I make Skype not use port 80?

Tags: apache-http-server, skype, port

I need this port for apache, how do I forbidden Skype from trying to use this port any more?

Answer (score 11):

Go to Options -> Advanced -> Connection

Unckeck the "Use port 80 and 443...."

Comment: This answer should be marked as accepted

Comment: I use Skype 7.0.0.102 for Windows. Unchecking "Use port 80 and 443...." did not help, but entering a port in the input field: "Use port ... for incoming connection" did the job. I used port 81.