# Forwarding port 80 of Windows 7 to virtual Ubuntu Server

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, port-forwarding

I'm running a virtual instance of Ubuntu Server using VirtualBox in Windows. To access the site hosted in it, I want to forward port 80 to Ubuntu, so that I can simply go to `localhost` to mess around with it.

[image]

But I'm not sure it won't mess up my regular connectivity. Is there anything that will botch the regular internet/network access?

Comment: Web server is running in Ubuntu, right?

Comment: @SachinDivekar Yes.

Comment: So your wording is wrong. Here you need to forward port 80 **to Ubuntu** from Windows. This will not affect your regular network/internet access.

Comment: @SachinDivekar Won't any HTTP requests, including those to websites on the internet, be routed through the virtual OS? And thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: It should not, because the outgoing packets would have destination ip as some public ip, so VB should not forward that request to VM. I think you better put 127.0.0.1 as Host IP in your rule.

Comment: So, have you forwarded it and is it working for you as you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not affect regular internet/network access

The only caveats would be if you were also running a webserver (or other service) listening on port 80.

If that were the case, it is also possible to forward another port (ex. 1234) to port 80 such that you could access it in a web browser by http://localhost:1234

Comment: I don't have anything listening on port 80 currently. At least nothing I'm aware of. Is there a way to check and make sure?

Comment: @Oxwivi you can check if there is something running on port 80 by using `telnet windows_host 80` from your Ubuntu machine.

Comment: You can also use "netstat -a -b" from an administrator command prompt  to get all processes including services

Comment: @arcyqwerty +1 just now I come to know that windows also has netstat available.

Comment: The solution for me was that port 80 was in use by Skype. Didn't even realize it. http://superuser.com/questions/140557/how-do-i-make-skype-not-use-port-80